# Is there a way to call a Python script from within Node.js and show it's results as soon as they are generated?

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous, child-process

I would like to execute a Python Script from within a Node.js app (Electron.js to be specific). I would like to show output as soon as it's generated. The Python script is a large one that takes a lot of time to process but it outputs data regularly.

I've tried this using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and [child_process](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/286/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-retrieve-output-data-and-errors-in-node-js). However when I execute the Python file the output is shown only when the program has ended.

I thought this could be done using `shell.on('message',function(){})` or `scriptExecution.stdout.on('data',function())` but apparently this is not the case.

Is this possible? How can I do it? Maybe using some other way...

Comment: I bet is possible - at least from Python it is. Either those hooks wait till the end, or maybe you need to flush the output on the Python side. I guess former. In Python you can open a process and read stdout from there as it comes. Maybe It's a different technique in node.

Comment: @antont thanks for your response, it does work. I will post a full answer to clarify.

Comment: cool, didn't know about the auto flush option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @antont pointed it out, obtaining Python results as soon as they appear on stdout this is easily done using a flush mechanism.

### How to do it

I've tested 3 ways to do it:

1. **Inside Python code**, pass a key word parameter to print:

   ```
   print('text', flush=True)
   ```
2. **Inside Python code**, using an explicit flush:

   ```
   import sys
   # Do this every time you want to flush
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```
3. **When calling the Python executable**, give it the option to always flush:

   ```
   python -u scriptName.py
   ```

   <sub>(see below for two examples using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).</sub>

### Node.js Examples

#### Using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

The key part of this example is `'-u'` in `pythonOptions: ['-u']`, if you remove this option Python won't automatically flush (unless you use methods 1 or 2 from above).

```
let PythonShellLibrary = require('python-shell');
let {PythonShell} = PythonShellLibrary;
let shell = new PythonShell('/home/user/showRandomWithSleep.py', {
    // The '-u' tells Python to flush every time
    pythonOptions: ['-u']
});
shell.on('message', function(message){
    window.console.log('message', message);
    window.console.log(new Date())
})
```

#### Using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

The key part of this example is `'-u'` in `spawn(pythonExecutable, ['-u', myPythonScript])`, if you remove this option Python won't automatically flush (unless you use methods 1 or 2 from above).

```
var myPythonScript = "/home/user/showRandomWithSleep.py";
var pythonExecutable = "python";
var uint8arrayToString = function(data) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
};
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// The '-u' tells Python to flush every time
const scriptExecution = spawn(pythonExecutable, ['-u', myPythonScript]);
scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
    window.console.log(new Date())
});
```

#### showRandomWithSleep.py, the python file used in the above examples

```
from random import *
import time
for i in range(5):
    print("showRandomWithSleep.py")
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    print(random())
    time.sleep(random()*5)
```

### Note

I tested the above examples and the results differ a little.

When using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) the prints are outputted for every `print()` line. However, when using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) the prints are outputted in blocks. I don't know why this happens.

### Links

- [How to execute a Python script and retrieve output (data and errors) in Node.js | Our Code World](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/286/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-retrieve-output-data-and-errors-in-node-js)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/1071459
- [How to flush STDOUT buffer in Python? - SysTutorials](https://www.systutorials.com/241780/how-to-flush-stdout-buffer-in-python/)
- [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)
- [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: you are a legend.